Google Apps Script methods returning "Proxy"
Google Apps Script is behaving really strangely for me and am wondering if anyone else has ever encountered the same issue and found a fix.
Instead of returning the objects / classes that the methods are supposed to return, they are instead returning "Proxy" objects, as you can see in the below screenshot which is from the debugger in the IDE:
Debugger image:

Here is the very simple code I used to generate the example of my issue, with 'my_url_here' obviously replaced with the real Google Sheets URL:
function test() {
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('my_url_here');

  Logger.log(ss);
}

I tried converting the "Proxy" to a usable object with Object.values( ) but that did not produce anything useful:
Using Object.values( ):

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Attached proposal:
function test() {  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('my_url_here');
   console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(ss).sort());
}

References:
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object)
Class console
Result


The language of this site is English. Please translate your answer. Also please explain how this answer the question.

OK, language changed
